# Understanding "802.11n-mode" options

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

The following values are the options available for the `802.11n-mode` option available from the router

```
bgn-mode Mixed
n-mode Only
bg-mode Mixed
g-mode Only
802.11b Only
```

How does work each one? And what is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi mode setup.

If you have N and G devices you would use bgn Mixed to allow for both N and G devices.

If you have N only, you would use n mode only.

We do not much B mode any more, and you may not have G devices.

N is faster than G is faster than B.

The extra modes in the list allow you to select the combination you need.

Comment: Thanks for the information - therefore `bgn-mode Mixed` is the best option right? There are old and new devices in the LAN, such as old laptops (2005), cellphones (2015) and laptops from 2016

Comment: Depending on the actual networks cards, bgn may well fit you best.